# Make Vuetify v-text-field component required by default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Currently, you can set rules that will work once the user changes the value of the input. For example:

Template part

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="title"
  label="Title"
></v-text-field>
```

Logic

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        title: '',
        email: '',
        rules: {
          required: value => !!value || 'Required.'
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

When the user focuses and removes focus from that element, or when the user deletes all its content, the required rule is triggered.

But what happens if we want to start with the rule enabled as soon as the component is mounted or created? Is there a way to achieve this?

I searched around vuetify but I could not find info about this nor examples in my humble google searches. I will appreciate help. I'm new in vue world. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

Create a [v-form](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms) and place your `textfields` inside the form. Don't forget to give your v-form a v-model and a ref too.
On mounted you can access the v-form via this.$refs and call .validate() just as Jesper described in his answer. In the `codesandbox` below you can see that the `textfields` immediately go red and display the "Required." text.

```
<v-form v-model="formValid" ref="myForm">
    <v-text-field label="Field 1" :rules="rules.required"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field label="Field 2" :rules="rules.required"></v-text-field>
</v-form>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formValid: false,
      rules: {
       required: [value => !!value || "Required."]
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
   this.$refs.myForm.validate();
 }
};
</script>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-c5w6h):

Comment: Work great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your validation a little bit to achieve this.

```
<ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }" ref="title">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="title"
      label="Title"
    ></v-text-field>
</ValidationProvider>
```

And then you should call `this.$refs.title.validate()`

If you trigger this when `mounted()` is called, it should validate all the fields right away, as you're requesting.

Comment: thanks for your help. Excuse my ignorance. Maybe I am doing something wrong but I receive the error `Cannot read property 'validateAll' of undefined` and if I try to console `this.$validator` it returns undefined

Comment: I suppose you have this right? `Vue.use(VeeValidate);`

Comment: Yes, in my `main.js` I also tried: `import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';` with `Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);` It did not work.

Comment: Ohh, so you're actually using V3, my bad, thought you were using V2. I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: @Peter Updated my answer :)

Comment: I could not still make it work. Yes, I am using v3.
In main.js I have
`import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
`
In the component...
`<div v-if="show">
<ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }" ref="name">
<v-text-field v-model="friend.name"
label="name">
</v-text-field>
</ValidationProvider>
`

And then, inside the method that changes `show`
`this.$nextTick(() => {
this.$refs.name. validate()
})},
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204583/discussion-between-peter-and-jesper).